# Determinant of a specific block matrix with 0 matrix in diagonals.

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am trying to determine the eigenvalues of a block matrix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} O & B \\ C & O \end{pmatrix}$$
where $O,B$ and $C$ are $n\times n$ matrices. How would I go about this, given that $B = kI$ for some constant $k$ and that $C$ is a symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues are known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block vector $\pmatrix{u\cr v\cr}$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$ if
$$ \eqalign{B v &= \lambda u\cr
            C u &= \lambda v\cr}$$
which (if $\lambda \ne 0$) is equivalent to $$\eqalign{CB v &= \lambda^2 v\cr u &= \lambda^{-1} B v}$$
I'll leave the case $\lambda=0$ to you.
So basically you take the square roots (both of them) of the eigenvalues of $CB$.